# Docker --build-arg defined but not mandatory

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions, docker-build

I'm building my docker image in a generic way so that might be used by multiple services, however not all the `--build-arg` will be present because it depends on the service that is being called on the GitHub Actions. My question is; is it possible to use only one or more `--build-arg` without using every `--build-arg`?

Command:

```bash
docker build \
  -f ${{ inputs.docker-location }} \
  -t $IMAGE_NAME:$TAG \
  --build-arg value1=${{secrets.value1}} \
  --build-arg value2=${{ secrets.value2}} \
  --build-arg value3=${{secrets.value3}} \
  --build-arg value4=${{ secrets.value4 }} .
```

So in this case I would only pass the value1 and value2, however, it fails because the rest of the values will be empty.

I know it works if all args are present, as I'm already using it, but wanted to expand it in a more generic way.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Did you try bash's conditional parameters ? Not certain it will work with github action's secret injection, but you could try and tell us. Ex: `${${{secrets.value1}}:+ --build-arg "value1=${{secrets.value1}}"}`. https://superuser.com/questions/802539/bash-optionally-passing-arguments-to-a-command shows an example and references.

Comment: I didn't try that one out but i just figure it out.

`--build-arg value1=${{secrets.value1 || 'default_value'}}`

It also works with empty, i found out that one as well. So the one above works if you want to default the value. For optional args you can leave it blank and it will work out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it possible to use only 1 or more --build -arg without using every --build-arg?

Yes, you can do this by defining a default `ARG` in the Dockerfile, e.g:

```
ARG value4=FOO
```

For more information: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#default-values

Comment: didn't thought about that one, but it makes sense! Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

In your pipeline check if those secrets are empty or not. If empty then give it a default value that you would handle in the Dockerfile appropriatly.

Comment: I think that's more or less what i did? (above answer)?

Comment: Yes, and in your Dockerfile you can do something like this `RUN if value1 != "default_value" then do the thing that needs to be done else do something default` (pseudo code)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a couple of things and this one work.

```
docker build -f ${{ inputs.docker-location }} \
          -t $IMAGE_NAME:$TAG \
          --build-arg value1=${{secrets.value1 || 'default_value'}} \
          --build-arg value2=${{ secrets.value2 || 'default_value'}} \
          --build-arg value3=${{secrets.value3 || 'default_value'}} \
          --build-arg value4=${{ secrets.value4 || 'default_value'}} .
```

Also figure it out that if you don't want to pass any value as if it empty, then you can just leave it without the default value, like below and the pipeline will ignore the empty args.
 `--build-arg value2=${{ secrets.value2}}`